# Probability question regarding the length of speeches

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to figure out the probability that more than 3 speeches will be completed in a 9-hour period. The length of speeches during a legislative assembly has approximately an exponential distribution with a mean of 90 minutes. Speeches are given 24-hours a day nonstop, with no break between the end of one speech and the start of the next. It is assumed that the time starts at the same time the speaker begins speaking. What is the probability that more than 3 speeches will be completed in a 9-hour period?
work thus far:

mean = 1.5h

n = 3

9h/1.5h = 6 speeches

Comment: Question seems ambiguous.  Interpretation (1) : The stopwatch starts at random, so that the current speaker may be at any point during his speech.  Notice the trap here that if (for example) the speaker has been speaking for an hour, chances are that his speech would be longer than normal.  Interpretation (2) : The stopwatch starts **just as** the speaker begins speaking.  You need to clarify which interpretation you intend.

Comment: @user2661923 True. Interpretation 1 is incorrect so I will edit this for clarity. Interpretation 2 is correct

Comment: More ambiguity:  a *particular* nine-hour period, or *some* nine-hour period within the day?

Comment: I believe some nine-hour period is what I am looking for